# Downgrading varnish service from 6.2.3 to 6.0.11 through RPM

Tags: rpm, varnish, varnish-vcl

while insatlling this package "MI-varnish6-modules.x86_64" in one of the varnish servers facing this error

```
Processing Dependency: libvarnishapi.so.2(LIBVARNISHAPI_2.0)(64bit) for package: MI-varnish6-modules-0.15.0-8.el7.x86_64
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
--> Processing Dependency: libvarnishapi.so.2()(64bit) for package: MI-varnish6-modules-0.15.0-8.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: MI-varnish6-modules-0.15.0-8.el7.x86_64 (/MI-varnish6-modules-0.15.0-8.el7.x86_64)
           Requires: libvarnishapi.so.2(LIBVARNISHAPI_2.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: MI-varnish6-modules-0.15.0-8.el7.x86_64 (/MI-varnish6-modules-0.15.0-8.el7.x86_64)
           Requires: libvarnishapi.so.2()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

the libraries are available in the specific folder "/nm/local/lib64/varnish/vmods/"

the source file i have added in form of tar :https://varnish-cache.org/downloads/varnish-6.0.11.tgz

i have tried to add more details on the spec file and tried to build it but its not working

Answer (score 0):

If the libraries weren't installed by RPM, as far as RPM is concerned, they don't exist. You need to go to where you got the RPM from and get the one that includes the base library.

Comment: I have used this link for downloading the rpm but I am not able to find that library on this page https://varnish-cache.org/downloads/varnish-6.0.11.tgz

Is there any other way to include that library in RPM